# Async Storage function for react native, the get action triggers the set operation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, local-storage, asyncstorage

#### **The method I use for React Local storage**

```
import {useState, useEffect, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

type Response<T> = [
    T,
    Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>,
]

function usePersistedState<T>(key:string, initialState: T): Response<T> {
 const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
        const storageValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (storageValue)
            return JSON.parse(storageValue);
        else
            return initialState
    });

 useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
    }, [state, setState]);

    return [state, setState];
}

export default usePersistedState;
```

#### The method I use for React Native Async storage

```
import {useState, useEffect, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

type Response<T> = [
    T,
    Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>,
]

function useAsyncStorage<T>(key:string, initialState: T): Response<T> {
const [state, setState] = useState(async () => {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        if (value){
            return value
        }
        else {
            return initialState
        }
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
    }, [state,setState]);
    // @ts-ignore
    return [state, setState];
}

export default useAsyncStorage;
```

In the use AsyncStorage function, the get operation triggers the set operation.

> const [getData,setData] = useAsyncStorage<DefaultData>("data",blankData);

> setData("data");

data has been saved.

> getData("data");

data was deleted.

**Current *Solution***

```
import {useState, useEffect, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { useAsyncStorage } from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

type Response<T> = [
    T,
    Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>,
]

function usePersistedState<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): Response<T> {
    const { getItem, setItem } = useAsyncStorage(key);
    const [state, setState] = useState<T>(defaultValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const data = await getItem();
            setState((data ? JSON.parse(data) : undefined) ?? defaultValue);
        })();
    }, [key]);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            await setItem(JSON.stringify(state));
        })();
    }, [key, state]);

    return [state, setState] as [T, typeof setState];
}

export default usePersistedState;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using it the same way in React? `getData` is not a function as it is your `state` in `useAsyncStorage`

Comment: yes, I am using this function in react.

Comment: But getData is not a function